# Is each Cassandra node required to communicate with all other nodes?

Tags: cassandra

The Cluster I want to deploy contains multiple Datacenters, the problem is: Not every Datacenter would be directly able to communicate to each other Datacenter. But indirectly, through few Datacenters that are able to communicate to the whole Cluster, they would be "connected".

Through testing it has become evident that this doesnt immediately work. So my question is: Can you somehow make it work? Is there maybe a way to use the fully connected Datacenters as "intermediate" Nodes for the (more) isolated ones?

Thanks in advance for your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's impossible on current Cassandra's version. Gossip Protocol requires every nodes communicating with each other.
A node tries to communicate with few nodes every second and it doesn't remember last nodes it reached.
Actually there's no way to restrict this communication between some DCs.
If you have this, you'll have a single point of failure. And we don't like this. :)